# NetworkStream.Length substitute

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networkstream

I am using a networkstream to pass short strings around the network.
Now, on the receiving side I have encountered an issue:
Normally I would do the reading like this

1. see if data is available at all
2. get count of data available
3. read that many bytes into a buffer
4. convert buffer content to string.

In code that assumes all offered methods work as probably intended, that would look something like this:

```
NetworkStream stream = someTcpClient.GetStream();
while(!stream.DataAvailable)
    ;

byte[] bufferByte;
stream.Read(bufferByte, 0, stream.Lenght);
AsciiEncoding enc = new AsciiEncoding();
string result = enc.GetString(bufferByte);
```

However, MSDN says that [NetworkStream.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not really implemented and will always throw an Exception when called.
Since the incoming data are of varying length I cannot hard-code the count of bytes to expect (which would also be a case of the magic-number antipattern).

**Question:**
If I cannot get an accurate count of the number of bytes available for reading, then how can I read from the stream properly, without risking all sorts of exceptions within [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

**EDIT**:
Although the provided answer leads to a better overall code I still want to share another option that I came across:
[TCPClient.Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives the bytes available to read. I knew there had to be a way to count the bytes in one's own inbox.

Comment: [This should help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37496/TCP-IP-Protocol-Design-Message-Framing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no guarantee that calls to `Read` on one side of the connection will match up 1-1 with calls to `Write` from the other side. If you're dealing with variable length messages, it's up to **you** to provide the receiving side with this information.

One common way to do this is to first work out the length of the message you're going to send and then send that length information first. On the receiving side, you then obtain the length first and then you know how big a buffer to allocate. You then call `Read` in a loop until you've read the correct number of bytes. Note that, in your original code, you're currently *ignoring* the return value from `Read`, which tells you how many bytes were actually read. In a single call and return, this could be as low as 1, even if you're asking for more than 1 byte.

Another common way is to decide on message "formats" - where e.g. message number 1 is always 32 bytes in length and has *X* structure, and message number 2 is 51 bytes in length and has *Y* structure. With this approach, rather than you sending the message *length* before sending the message, you send the format information instead - first you send "here comes a message of type 1" and then you send the message.

A further common way, if applicable, is to use some form of sentinels - if your messages will never contain, say, a byte with value `0xff` then you scan the received bytes until you've received an `0xff` byte, and then everything before that byte was the message you wanted to receive.

But, whatever you want to do, whether its one of the above approaches, or something else, it's up to *you* to have your sending and receiving sides work together to allow the receiver to discover each message.

---

I forgot to say but a further way to change everything around is - if you want to exchange *messages*, and don't want to do any of the above fiddling around, then switch to something that works at a higher level - e.g. WCF, or HTTP, or something else, where those systems already take care of message framing and you can, then, just concentrate on what to do with your messages.

Comment: I am using ascii encoding, so I could for example use 0x04 End of Transmission. What a coincidence that such a character exists.  Thank you a lot. I thought since reading is my side of the job, that I could just take a look into *my* stream and read that much.

Comment: @Mark, yea its almost like ASCII was based upon [a protocol that originally ran over networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `StreamReader` to read stream to the end

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(someTcpClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: This will block till the socket is closed.

Comment: How else will you know that the stream is ended?

Comment: @VladimirSachek I actually want to use this for communication, so  want to keep the socket open for a not preset amount of time.